# How to load a website that requires jinitiator?

Tags: java, websites

The link for this website is:

http://emisas1.moe.gov.jo:7778/forms/frmservlet

I can't install jinitiator on linux. So, what version of java should I use instead? and what browser should I use? And is this site safe to use?

Answer (score 1):

Add the **webupd8 team java ppa** to your system using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Type `sudo apt-get update` and install both `oracle-java8-installer` and `oracle-java8-set-default`.

This will install the complete *Oracle JDK* on your system, including the *java plugin* for Firefox and all **NPAPI** compatible browsers.  This means that all **PPAPI** only compatible browsers, like Chrome, Chromium, will not work because there is no **PPAPI** java plugin.

Comment: --2016-06-16 06:32:43--  (try: 5)  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u91-b14/jdk-8u91-linux-i586.tar.gz?AuthParam=1466049622_3e88c2a1de003c1371466e927c51d131;
Connecting to download.oracle.com; (download.oracle.com)|62.139.204.70|:80... connected.;
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.;
Giving up.;
;
download failed;
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.;

Comment: dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):;
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1;
Setting up gsfonts-x11 (0.22) ...;
Errors were encountered while processing:;
 oracle-java8-installer;
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1);

Comment: It seems the installer was unable to download the required package, which leads to connectivity issues.  If this was not a temporary situation, maybe because the server was down at the time, then these issues have to be checked.  Some kind of firewall blocking the connection maybe, or proxy?

Comment: I tried to run the command again, and the programs were installed, but there is no changes, and this site  http://emisas1.moe.gov.jo:7778/forms/frmservlet tells me that I need to install a plugin.

Comment: @user37421 With which browser are you trying to access the page?

Comment: @ThomasWard I used firefox.